# How to map form values to an object for ASP.NET MVC HTTP-Post scenario?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i have a simple form for an ASP.NET MVC application. I have a form property that is named differently (for whatever reason) to the real property name.

I know there's `[Bind(Exlcude="", Include="")]` attribute, but that doesn't help me in this case.

I also don't want to have a `(FormsCollection formsCollection)` argument in the Action method signature.

is there another way I can define the mapping?

eg.

```
<%= Html.ValidationMessage("GameServer", "*")%>
```

results in ..

```
<select id="GameServer" name="GameServer">
    <option value="2">PewPew</option>
</select>
```

this needs to map to..

```
myGameServer.GameServerId = 2; // PewPew.
```

cheers!

Comment: <%= Html.ValidationMessage("GameServer", "*")%> ?

Is this example correct???

Comment: Nope - i'll fix that later on when i get home. it should have been a text box. was a bad copty/paste error.

Answer (score 1):

i believe you will need to define it in your controller arguments or else it wouldnt have any clue what to accept.

```
public ActionResult GameServer(string GameServer){
    GServer myGameServer = new GServer();
    myGameServer.GameServerId.ToString() = GameServer;
    return View("GameServer");
}
```

you can pass in the name/id of the parameter your trying to go for on your view page, it will automagically know the value to recieve based on the id on your view.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with having a FormCollection passed as argument? I had to do the same thing as you and I just excluded the GameServer property in the BindAttribute.

Another thing you have to note is that `Html.ValidationMessage("GameServer", "*")` won't work because the underlying model doesn't contain a GameServer property. You have to add it to the model. I don't know if there is a better way to do it, I didn't find but it was required to make `ValidationMessage` works

Comment: That ValidateMessage line is a mistake. i copied/pasted the wrong line. it should have been a textbox. I'll re-edit that when i get home. I'm thinking about using a forms collection .. but i was curious to see if it can be done WITHOUT it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create you own ModelBinder ([see how to](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Model_Binders_in_ASPNET_MVC.aspx)) to do the custom mapping.
An overkill IMO, but you might have your reasons...